# Условие с разным url на javaScript

Tags: javascript, url

День добрый. Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы пользователь переходя на определенную страницу получал сообщение,а переходя на все последующие - не получал.

Например, я хочу,чтобы выводилось сообщение "hey!" по url /stati/ , но при этом на /stati/?page=2 (3,4,5...). выводился "hey2!".
Спасибо за внимание.

```
<script>
if(location.pathname=="/stati/") 
{
alert('hey!')
}
else
{
alert('hey2!')
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(location.search.startsWith('?page')) {
    alert('hey!')
} else {
    alert('hey2')
}
```

как то так

Comment: @Armen - Ваш способ выдает ('hey2') на всех страницах. А вот у товарища Павел Ткаченко все правильно! Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно разделить URL на части, а потом просто реализовать простую проверку

```
let url = window.location.href.split("/");

for (let i = 0; i < url.length; i++){
    if(url[i] === "stati"){
        if(url[i + 1] === "1"){
            alert("hey!");
        } else {
            alert("hey2");
        }
    }
}
```